# Why does Knex insert null values into my table database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, knex.js

I have a SQLite database connected via express and have controllers to connect front end with backend using express routes.

> Table database
>
> ```
>   return knex.schema.createTable('stocks', (table)  => {
>           table.string('ticker')
>           table.date('date')
>           table.integer('open')
>           table.integer('close')
>           table.integer('high')
>           table.integer('last')
>           table.integer('volume')
>         })
>         .then(() => {
>          
>           console.log('Table \'stocks\' created')
>         })
>         .catch((error) => {
>           console.error(`There was an error creating table: ${error}`)
>         })
>       }
>     })
>     .then(() => {
>       // Log success message
>       console.log('Ayree')
>     })
>     .catch((error) => {
>       console.error(`There was an error setting up the database: ${error}`)
>     })
> ```
>
> Knex Insert Rows
>
> ```
> exports.booksCreate = async (req, res) => {
>   // Add new book to database
>   knex('stocks')
>     .insert({ // insert new record, a book
>       "ticker": req.body.ticker,
>       'date': req.body.date,
>       'open': req.body.open,
>       'close': req.body.close,
>       'high': req.body.high,
>       'last': req.body.last,
>       'volume': req.body.volume,
>     })
>     .then(() => {
>       // Send a success message in response
>       res.json({ message: ` \'${req.body.ticker}\' added at ${req.body.date} created.` })
>     })
>     .catch(err => {
>       // Send a error message in response
>       res.json({ message: `There was an error creating ${req.body.ticker}  ${err}` })
>     })
> }
> ```
>
> React Front End

```
// Create Bookshelf component
export const Bookshelf = () => {
  // Prepare states
   const [stock, setStock] = useState([])
   const [stockApi, setStockApi] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  // Fetch all books on initial render
  useEffect(() => {
   
    getStockData();
    handleBookCreate();
  }, [])


  //StockData
const getStockData = ()  => { 
    axios
    .get("http://api.marketstack.com/v1/intraday/latest?access_key=72ad8c2f489983f30aaedd0181414b43&symbols=AAPL"       )
    .then( da => {
       setStock(da.data.data[0]) 
        console.log(da.data.data[0])
    } )
} 

// Create new book
  const handleBookCreate = () => {
    // Send POST request to 'books/create' endpoint
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:4001/books/create', { 
        ticker: stock.symbol,
        date: stock.date,
        open: stock.open,
        close: stock.close,
        high: stock.high,
        last: stock.last,
        volume: stock.volume,
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)

        // Fetch all books to refresh
        // the books on the bookshelf list
        fetchBooks()
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(`There was an error creating the ${stock} book: ${error}`))
  }
```

The issue here is in the front end when i use `stock.symbol` i get a value of null but when i substitute stock.symbol with "text" i get the value text. What am i doing wrong here? Thanks!

P.S - Here is const stock

```
close: 115.08
date: "2020-10-09T00:00:00+0000"
exchange: "IEXG"
high: 116.4
last: 114.97
low: 114.5901
open: 116.25
symbol: "AAPL"
volume: 82322071
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: try to replace stock.symbol with stock["symbol"], from your description it gets missing somewhere in the frontend. Maybe you override it at some point. Also try to log JSON.stringify(stock) just before sending it out.

Comment: Hey Mikael! I tried doing stock["symbol"] and still getting a null value. I think the issue here is that when I call the function to create a new book (handleBookCreate) in the return statement i get the values. How can i get the values without calling the function in the return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time reading about HTTP calls and how they are executed.  This solution worked for me.

```
 useEffect( () => {

const fetchData = async ( ) => { 

  const getit =  await getStockData(); setStock(getit); 
    handleBookCreate(getit); 
    } 
         fetchData();

  }, [])
```

Basically on intial render `useEffect`, make the API call `getStockData()`and the await will make setting the stock `setStock` hook work after the promise have been executed. Only then the `stock` would contain the data needed for `handleBookCreate()` to send a POST request to the server router to execute the function to insert a record in my table database.